# facing the network congestion issues with ebpf

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, ebpf

I am using the below eBPF program in my vm to allow only icmp packets and to drop the tcp packets.

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/icmp.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <linux/pkt_cls.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <linux/bpf_perf_event.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY);
    __uint(max_entries, 1);
    __type(key, int);
    __type(value, uint64_t);
} timestamp_map SEC(".maps");

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY);
    __uint(max_entries, 1);
    __type(key, int);
    __type(value, uint64_t);
} counter_map SEC(".maps");

SEC("xdp")
int icmp_timestamp(struct xdp_md *xdp) {
    // Load the Ethernet protocol
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)xdp->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)xdp->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;

    if (data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) > data_end)
        return XDP_DROP;

    // Process only IP packets
    if (eth->h_proto == htons(ETH_P_IP)) {

        if (data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct iphdr) > data_end)
            return XDP_DROP;

        // Load the IP protocol
        struct iphdr *ip = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr);

        if (ip->protocol == IPPROTO_ICMP) {
            // Load the timestamp
            uint64_t timestamp = bpf_ktime_get_ns();

            // Increment the packet counter
            int key_counter = 0;
            uint64_t *counter = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&counter_map, &key_counter);
            if (counter) {
                (*counter)++;
            }

            // Store the timestamp in the per-CPU map
            int key_timestamp = 0;
            bpf_map_update_elem(&timestamp_map, &key_timestamp, &timestamp, BPF_ANY);

            // Allow the packet to pass
            return XDP_PASS;
        }
    }

    // Drop the packet for non-ICMP or non-IP packets
    return XDP_DROP;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

After successfully compiling and loading the above program, I am using the command
`sudo bpftool net attach xdp id 40 dev enp0s3` to attach the program to xdp hook and then it to interface.

But after attaching the program to interface, I am facing the network congestion issues and unable to send data by pinging to it. Unable to know how to resolve it.

Comment: You typically need more than just IP + ICMP to maintain connection. For starters ARP and if you don't have a static IP, DHCP. LACP if you are using link aggregation ect. So first do a packet dump for a while to see what protocols you are actually using before dropping everything